# How to restore Microsoft SQL Server database from .sql file?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have 3,5 GiB .sql file with MS SQL Server database dump (created from MS SQL Server Management Studio). How to restore this database now?

Comment: Just execute the .sql, perhaps? Edit - from command line, of course

Comment: I'd probably use command line to run the SQL file - don't try to open it with SSMS.